# How to set permanent page zoom in incognito mode in Google Chrome?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, browser, chromium, google-chrome-devtools

In the Google Chrome settings, you can permanently set the value to `zoom` only in normal mode; in the incognito mode, it is reset upon a new launch. Now I use `--incognito --force-device-scale-factor=2` on startup, but the command `--force-device-scale-factor=2` does not the same as `zoom`. How can i do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Negative answer : Chrome saves zoom settings on a per site basis,
but the setting is not saved in incognito window
(as are not saved all other settings).

For information, Chrome used to work the way you ask up until
the 2010 bug-report
[Issue 43107: Don't remember incognito zoom changes](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=43107).

The poster of the bug-report complained that zoom settings were being
saved in incognito mode. The developer responsible for the user-interface
then accepted the report and made the change that brought us
to the current situation.

This can only be changed by the Chrome developers, and is not
something that us users can do.